# Can't install Inkscape's dependency libmagick++ on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, xubuntu

I am trying to (unsuccessfully) install Inkscape on Xubuntu 16.04.
If I do `sudo apt-get install inkscape` this is what I get:

```
sudo apt-get install inkscape

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 inkscape : Depends: libmagick++-6.q16-5v5 (>= 8:6.8.9.9-7) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libimage-magick-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I naviely tried to simply install `libmagick++`, but here's the result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libmagick++-dev' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagick++-6.q16-5' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagick++-6.q16-6' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagick++-6.q16-7' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickcore-6.q16' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagick++-6.defaultquantum-dev' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickwand-6.q16-2' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickwand-6.q16-3' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickwand-6-headers' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagick++6-dev' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagick9-dev' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickcore-6.q16-1-extra' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagick++-6-headers' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickwand5' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickcore-extra' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickcore-6.defaultquantum-dev' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickcore-6-headers' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickcore-6-arch-config' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickwand-6.defaultquantum-dev' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickwand-6.q16-dev' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickcore-6.q16-2' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickcore-6.q16-3' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagick++9-dev' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickwand-dev' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagick++-6.q16-5v5' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagick++-6.q16-dev' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagick-dev' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickcore-6.q16-dev' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagick6-dev' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagickcore-dev' for regex 'libmagick+'
Note, selecting 'libmagick++-6.q16-dev' instead of 'libmagick++-6.defaultquantum-dev'
Note, selecting 'libmagickcore-6.q16-dev' instead of 'libmagickcore-6.defaultquantum-dev'
Note, selecting 'libmagickwand-6.q16-dev' instead of 'libmagickwand-6.defaultquantum-dev'
Note, selecting 'graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat' instead of 'libmagick-dev'
libmagick++-6-headers is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16xenial0).
libmagick++-6-headers set to manually installed.
libmagick++-6.q16-dev is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16xenial0).
libmagick++-6.q16-dev set to manually installed.
libmagickcore-6.q16-3 is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16xenial0).
libmagickcore-6.q16-3 set to manually installed.
libmagickwand-6-headers is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16xenial0).
libmagickwand-6-headers set to manually installed.
libmagickcore-6-arch-config is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16xenial0).
libmagickcore-6-arch-config set to manually installed.
libmagickwand-6.q16-dev is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16xenial0).
libmagickwand-6.q16-dev set to manually installed.
libmagick++-6.q16-7 is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16xenial0).
libmagick++-6.q16-7 set to manually installed.
libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16xenial0).
libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra set to manually installed.
libmagickwand-6.q16-3 is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16xenial0).
libmagickwand-6.q16-3 set to manually installed.
libmagickcore-6.q16-dev is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16xenial0).
libmagickcore-6.q16-dev set to manually installed.
libmagickcore-6-headers is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16xenial0).
libmagickcore-6-headers set to manually installed.
libmagick++-dev is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16xenial0).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat : Conflicts: libmagick++-dev
                                       Conflicts: libmagick++-dev:i386
                                       Conflicts: libmagickcore-dev but 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 is to be installed
                                       Conflicts: libmagickcore-dev:i386
 imagemagick-6-common : Breaks: libmagickcore-6.q16-2 (< 8:6.9.6.2+dfsg-3~) but 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 is to be installed
 libmagickcore-6.q16-2 : Depends: imagemagick-common (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15)
 libmagickwand-6.q16-2 : Depends: imagemagick-common (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I also tried installing Inkscape from the PPA with the same results. Any and all pointers would be appreciated.
None of the similar questions I found had this issue.

Many thanks!

UPDATE:

as suggested by N0rbert, I've run `sudo apt-get update` and retried `sudo apt-get install inkscape`, but the results are the same.
Additionally:

```
apt-cache policy inkscape libmagick++-6.q16-5v5
inkscape:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.91-7ubuntu2
  Version table:
     0.91-7ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libmagick++-6.q16-5v5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15
  Version table:
     8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

grep -ir "^deb" /etc/apt/ --include=*.list
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ xenial partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://qgis.org/debian xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://cloud.r-project.org//bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/ lsb3.2 main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dropbox.list:deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/apandada1-ubuntu-brightness-controller-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/apandada1/brightness-controller/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mendeleydesktop.list:deb https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/otto-kesselgulasch-ubuntu-gimp-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

Please let me know if any more info is useful!

Comment: FYI: Xubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://xubuntu.org/release/16-04/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` on your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Xubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: Hi, I am aware that this version is no longer supported, there are reasons why I haven't upgraded. Is there a solution for the problem at hand though?

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update`, retry by `sudo apt-get install inkscape` then add output of `apt-cache policy inkscape libmagick++-6.q16-5v5` and `grep -ir "^deb" /etc/apt/ --include=*.list` to the question (or upload to pastebin if they are long).

Comment: I've added the requested info